# Adding CSS class to anchor link in markdown (Hugo)

Tags: html, css, markdown, hugo

I'm using anchor links in my `.markdown` document like so:

`# {#infrared}`

This works fine but I wanted to implement the following CSS so that the link scrolls to the middle of the page and not at the top:

```
.anchor {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(-50vh);
}
```

How can I add the class `anchor` to my anchor link in the markdown document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on this answer [here](https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/adding-multiple-css-classes-to-an-anchor-link/30211/2?u=thedivtagguy), we have:

> As per the README 1 of Goldmark the Markdown processor that is
> currently turned on by default in Hugo:
>
> Currently only headings support attributes…

```
## heading ## {#id .className attrName=attrValue class="class1 class2"}
 
## heading {#id .className attrName=attrValue class="class1 class2"}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think overall markdown supports html tags for example you should be able to use

```html
<p class="anchor">text...</p>
```

but either way if It wont really work you have few other options.
For example "Fenced Code Attributes":

````
```{.red .numberLines startFrom="1"}
Here is a paragraph.

And another.
```
````

This is really example copied from docs,
more options really are available here:
https://lifelongprogrammer.blogspot.com/2019/01/how-to-style-markdown-with-css.html

Comment: Markdown should infact support this, but I'm building this with RStudio and for some reason, the HTML does not get rendered on the page. Thank you for your answer though, I'll go through the links too :)

Comment: I think it supports Fenced Code Attributes but I'm not 100% sure on this